# How can I correct if an `Objective-C` API is documented under the `iOS` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation, documentation-topics

As an iOS app developer, I am not able to differentiate the topics between [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tags. Because most of the topics are shuffled between these two tags. Even Swift also comes into this picture. Why can't we put these into one place?

How do I correct if an Objective C API is documented under the `iOS` tag? For instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/979/nsattributedstring#t=201607230602564893911), the `NSAttributedString` API is documented in `iOS` instead of `Objective-C`.

Comment: Same problem for [C#/.NET](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329171/3764814) here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There *should* be a big difference. Objective-C is a *programming language*, just like C or C++. Therefore, for the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag, you should be documenting things about the Objective-C programming language.

The fact that Objective-C is used a lot in iOS programming is merely coincidental and has nothing to do with the language itself. If I wanted to write a Windows application in Objective-C, I could certainly do it, and none of the iOS-specific stuff that is cluttering up the Objective-C documentation is going to be useful to me. I want to know about the language features, how it's different from C, what compilers I can use for it, etc. etc.

All of the iOS-specific stuff (libraries, APIs, etc.) should go under the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag documentation. Just like the macOS-specific stuff should go under the [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) tag documentation. And the Windows-specific stuff should go under the [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag documentation. You get the idea. Libraries/APIs are different from languages. A library can (generally) be used with many languages; a language can use many different libraries.

The same thing is true for Swift, coincidentally. It's a *language*, documented under the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag. The fact that Apple developed it and uses it extensively for iOS and macOS development is not important. Google has recently considered adopting Swift as a new programming language for the Android platform. If that happens, it'll end the Apple-specificity of the language, making documentation that talks exclusively about iOS APIs rather confusing, if not downright worthless.

Comment: I don't understand the question. iOS APIs should be documented under the [ios] tag, not the [objective-c] tag. My answer couldn't be more clear about that.

Comment: @Code Gray Please check my update. Hope you got my point.

Comment: It is already in the right place! If it were not, you could flag it and ask for a moderator to move it. Again I wonder, what is unclear about my answer?