# How could we better handle topic requests on the wrong tag?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Since the start of the public documentation beta, many topic requests have been posed to the [C# Language](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23) docs.

The issue is that *most* of these requests should have been posted to the [.NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net) section instead, as they are not language specific. And I believe we should keep language docs separate from framework docs, as other .NET languages could benefit from the same docs.

How should we handle this? Here are a few thoughts:

- Do nothing: let people write duplicated topics in both tags. I don't think this is the best solution, obviously.
- Comment that the topic request should have been submitted to a different tag and dismiss it. This is what I've been doing, for lack of a better solution.
- Implement a dismiss reason which would redirect the topic request to a different tag, so we could quickly send the request where it belongs without actually dismissing it altogether. This would be a useful feature IMO, but we'd need to ensure the topic doesn't already exist in the target tag.
- Improve the "request topic" interface by allowing a tag-specific message. For C# it could be something like this:

  > *Please make sure your the topic you're requesting is specific to the C# language. Please submit .NET Framework topic requests to its dedicated section.*

  We'd also have to define *how* the process of editing this text would work.

I don't know if other tags have a similar issue, but addressing this *before* we get more requests than we can handle could be nice.

What do you think? Any other ideas?

Comment: Other tags do have this problem [I assure you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329074/215552).